# SQL Subquery CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
  ac.ac_code,    
  (SELECT CASE
              WHEN SUM(L.l_valuedr) - SUM(L.l_valuecr) >= 0 THEN SUM(L.l_valuedr) - SUM(L.l_valuecr)
              ELSE 0
          END AS dr,
          CASE
              WHEN SUM(L.l_valuedr) - SUM(L.l_valuecr) < 0 THEN SUM(L.l_valuecr) - SUM(L.l_valuedr)
              ELSE 0
          END AS cr
   FROM Ledger AS L
   WHERE (l_date < '09/08/2014')
     AND (l_accode = ac.ac_code)
  ) AS bf,
  CASE
    WHEN SUM(Ledger_2.l_valuedr) - SUM(Ledger_2.l_valuecr) >= 0 THEN SUM(Ledger_2.l_valuedr) - SUM(Ledger_2.l_valuecr)
    ELSE 0
  END AS dr,
  CASE
    WHEN SUM(Ledger_2.l_valuedr) - SUM(Ledger_2.l_valuecr) < 0 THEN SUM(Ledger_2.l_valuecr) - SUM(Ledger_2.l_valuedr)
    ELSE 0
  END AS cr
FROM Ac_Accounts AS ac
INNER JOIN Ac_Costelements ON ac.ac_costelement = Ac_Costelements.ce_code
INNER JOIN Ledger AS Ledger_2 ON ac.ac_code = Ledger_2.l_accode
WHERE (Ledger_2.l_date >= '09/08/2014')
  AND (Ledger_2.l_date <= '09/15/2014')
  AND (Ledger_2.l_accode = ac.ac_code)
GROUP BY ac.ac_code
```

Showing this Error:

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: Your problem lies in your second column.  You have a select statement that is returning more than one row and column

Comment: @paqogomez -- and more than one column, as indicated by the error message.

Comment: Instead of SQL Subquery try using [APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), which allows you to select more than one column. Here is a sample [CROSS APPLY Explained](http://sqlserverplanet.com/sql-2005/cross-apply-explained)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simplify your query as follows:

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  ac.ac_code,
            Value1 = SUM(CASE WHEN l.l_date < '20140908' THEN l.l_valuedr - l.l_valuecr ELSE 0 END),
            Value2 = SUM(CASE WHEN l.l_date >= '20140908' THEN l.l_valuedr - l.l_valuecr ELSE 0 END)
    FROM    Ac_Accounts AS ac
            INNER JOIN Ac_Costelements AS c
                ON ac.ac_costelement = c.ce_code
            INNER JOIN Ledger AS l 
                ON ac.ac_code = l.l_accode
    WHERE   l.l_date <= '20140915'
    GROUP BY ac.ac_code
)
SELECT  ac_code,
        dr = CASE WHEN Value1 >= 0 THEN Value1 END,
        cr = CASE WHEN Value1 < 0 THEN Value1 * -1 END,
        dr = CASE WHEN Value1 >= 0 THEN Value2 END,
        cr = CASE WHEN Value1 < 0 THEN Value2 * -1 END
FROM    CTE;
```

Rather than using a correlated subquery to get the amounts before a given date, and get the amount after that date in the main query, you can get both amounts within the same query by using `CASE` inside the SUM.

Then by moving some of the logic to a subquery you can simplify the query by reducing the number of sums done.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing two case statements, why not move them together?
Go from this:

```
(SELECT CASE
              WHEN SUM(L.l_valuedr) - SUM(L.l_valuecr) >= 0 THEN SUM(L.l_valuedr) - SUM(L.l_valuecr)
              ELSE 0
          END AS dr,
          CASE
              WHEN SUM(L.l_valuedr) - SUM(L.l_valuecr) < 0 THEN SUM(L.l_valuecr) - SUM(L.l_valuedr)
              ELSE 0
          END AS cr
   FROM Ledger AS L
   WHERE (l_date < '09/08/2014')
     AND (l_accode = ac.ac_code)) AS bf
```

To something like this:

```
(SELECT CASE
         WHEN SUM(L.l_valuedr) - SUM(L.l_valuecr) >= 0 
         THEN SUM(L.l_valuedr) - SUM(L.l_valuecr)
         ELSE SUM(L.l_valuecr) - SUM(L.l_valuedr)
        END AS newcolumn
   FROM Ledger AS L
   WHERE (l_date < '09/08/2014')
     AND (l_accode = ac.ac_code)) AS bf
```